# Django Infinity as datetime default

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm struggling to see how I can add a datetime field with an infinity end date.

Setting the default to 'infinity' results in a Django.core exception

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'infinity' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

NB: This is not the same as defining it Null (None). It's specially supported in postgres as just a string condition check for example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dt = 'infinity'; // or
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT isfinite(dt);
```

Nulls won't show in this, nor can you do a between condition on a Null value unless you COALESCE it, but that will result in a sequential scan.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like Django doesn't support infinity, since python datetime which it relies on doesn't support it either. You could try setting it to [`datetime.max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.max) instead if the purpose is just for comparisons between times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django ORM converts `infinity` to `datetime.max`, so consider using `datetime.max` instead:

```
$ psql -d yourdb
yourdb=# UPDATE app_yourmodel SET last_login = 'infinity' WHERE id = 1;

$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> from app.models import YourModel
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> YourModel.objects.get(id=1).last_login
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>
>>> datetime.max
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```